# XSLT sequential processing

Tags: xslt, sequential

Within class xyz only, I want to examine exactly two divs and their classnames.
If classname="yes" then output '1'.
If classname="no" then output '0'.

```
<div class="xyz">
    <div class="no"></div>
    <div class="yes"></div>
</div>
```

Desired output: 0 1

```
<div class="xyz">
    <div class="yes"></div>
    <div class="yes"></div>
</div>
```

Desired output: 1 1

.. etc ..
Finding the first is easy but how do I do it "sequentially"?

Comment: can you post the XSLT, tried at your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive processing can be used as in the XSLT-1.0 code below:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='xyz']/div[@class='no']">
        <xsl:text>0 </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='xyz']/div[@class='yes']">
        <xsl:text>1 </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The 3rd template processes all the nodes recursively, starting with document node. The first two templates do the desired output for @class with 'yes' and 'no'.

Comment: Thanks. That did it!